# Db2 change a column to row update timestamp

Tags: sql, db2, timestamp, last-modified

In my table I've a column MODIFIED with type TIMESTAMP.
I want to update this column automatically when the row is updated

I can use this for a new column

```
alter table my_table add column last_updated timestamp not null
 generated by default for each row on update as row change timestamp
```

But I can't use this to edit the existing column to do the updating automatically

```
alter table my_table alter column modified set data type timestamp 
 not null generated by default for each row on update as row change timestamp
```

Am I using the alter correctly?

the error message is

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=alter table my_table alter column modified;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<values>, DRIVER=3.50.152
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: I _think_ you may be only able to add the column, given the way the reference documentation is laid out (that is, the row-change-timestamp portion is under `ADD COLUMN`, not `ALTER COLUMN`).  Is there any problem adding the new column, moving the data over (if necessary), then dropping the old one?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse its just the process of adding the column, moving the data, dropping the column, add the column again with new config, move data over and drop the temp column with couple of reorgs thrown in. with 9.7 at least I could rename column but I'm using 9.5

Comment: Create a new table, then, with the new column, place data into it, then swapping the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an article here 
http://ibmsystemsmag.blogs.com/db2utor/2008/01/automate-row-ch.html

***essentially it says***

- *You cannot use the ALTER TABLE statement to convert a column on an
  existing table to use the as-row-change-timestamp-clause. You must
  either drop the table and recreate with the column defined with the
  as-row-change-timestamp-clause or ALTER the table and add a new
  column with the as-row-change-timestamp-clause.*

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to add new column with timestamp on using below query.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
  add column UPDATED_DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS FOR EACH ROW
  ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the column exists, you use a slightly different syntax to alter the data type and attributes:

```
alter table my_table alter column my_column set generated by default ...
```